# How to differentiate between a .ts file and a .d.ts

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following folder structure:

```
-+ src/
---+ index.ts
---+ foobar.ts
---+ routes/
-----+ router.d.ts
-----+ router.ts
```

How would I be able to import only the `router.ts` file in `index.ts` and import `router.d.ts` in `foobar.ts`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to import .d.ts files. Typescript uses them automagically for type information.

Comment: `.d.ts` files are generally intended to apply types to existing *Javascript* code. If the two files represent the same module, then the types should just be in the `.ts` file. If the `.ts` file has no types at all, then rename it to `.js`. If they're different modules, then they shouldn't have the same name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. TypeScript's module resolution algorithm will always prefer the `.ts` file over a `.d.ts` file of the same name, since it assumes the latter is a build output of the former. You should name your files differently if you want them to both be in the same compilation.